# how to use ussdinterceptor in android

Tags: android

How to use ussdinterceptor service in android is question which is asked a lot. and the  responses for it are poor.
this is my response.

first the service it self.

classes for the package  com.example.ussdcodes

BootReceiver.java

```
package com.example.ussdcodes;

//import com.example.ussdcodes.R;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("USSDService", context.getString(R.string.service_started));
        context.startService(new Intent(context,USSDDumbExtendedNetworkService.class));
    }

}
```

USSDDumbExtendedNetworkService.java

```
package com.example.ussdcodes;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PatternMatcher;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;





import com.android.internal.telephony.IExtendedNetworkService;
//import com.android.internal.telephony.IExtendedNetworkService;
import com.example.ussdcodes.R;

/**
 * Service implements IExtendedNetworkService interface. 
 * USSDDumbExtendedNetworkService
 * Service must have name "com.android.ussd.IExtendedNetworkService" of the intent declared
 * in the Android manifest file so com.android.phone.PhoneUtils class bind
 * to this service after system rebooted.
 * Please note service is loaded after system reboot! 
 * Your application must check is system rebooted. 
 * @see Util#syslogHasLine(String, String, String, boolean)   
 */
public class USSDDumbExtendedNetworkService extends Service {
    public static final String TAG = "CommandusUSSDExtNetSvc";
    public static final String LOG_STAMP = "*USSDTestExtendedNetworkService bind successfully*";
    public static final String URI_SCHEME = "ussdcodes";
    public static final String URI_AUTHORITY = "android.com";
    public static final String URI_PATH = "/";
    public static final String URI_PAR = "return";
    public static final String URI_PARON = "on";
    public static final String URI_PAROFF = "off";
    public static final String MAGIC_ON = ":ON;)";
    public static final String MAGIC_OFF = ":OFF;(";
    public static final String MAGIC_RETVAL = ":RETVAL;(";
    public static final String RESULT = "result";

    private static boolean mActive = true;
    private static CharSequence mRetVal = null;
    private Context mContext = null;
    private String msgUssdRunning = "USSD running..."; 

    final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (Intent.ACTION_INSERT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                mContext = context;
                if (mContext != null) {
                    msgUssdRunning = mContext.getString(R.string.USSD_run);
                    mActive = true;
                    Log.d(TAG, "activate");
                }
            } else if (Intent.ACTION_DELETE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                mContext = null;
                mActive = false;
                Log.d(TAG, "deactivate");
            }
        }
    };

    private final IExtendedNetworkService.Stub mBinder = new IExtendedNetworkService.Stub() {
        @Override
        public void setMmiString(String number) throws RemoteException {
            Log.d(TAG, "setMmiString: " + number);
            Intent intent =new Intent("com.example.ussdcodes.setmmistring") ;
           intent.putExtra("ussdCode", number);
           sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getMmiRunningText() throws RemoteException {
            Log.d(TAG, "getMmiRunningText: " + msgUssdRunning);
            return msgUssdRunning;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getUserMessage(CharSequence text)
                throws RemoteException {
       /*     if (MAGIC_ON.contentEquals(text)) {
                mActive = true;
                Log.d(TAG, "control: ON");
                return text;
            } else {
                if (MAGIC_OFF.contentEquals(text)) {
                    mActive = false;
                    Log.d(TAG, "control: OFF");
                    return text;
                } else {
                    if (MAGIC_RETVAL.contentEquals(text)) {
                        mActive = false;
                        Log.d(TAG, "control: return");
                        return mRetVal;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!mActive) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getUserMessage deactivated: " + text);
                return text;
            } */
            String s = text.toString();
            // store s to the !
            Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                .scheme(URI_SCHEME)
                .authority(URI_AUTHORITY)
                .path(URI_PATH)
                .appendQueryParameter(URI_PAR, text.toString())
                .build();
          //  Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, uri) ;
        //    Intent intent =new Intent("com.example.ussdcodes", uri) ;
            Intent intent =new Intent("com.example.ussdcodes.getusermsg") ;
            intent.putExtra("result", s);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            mActive = false;
            mRetVal = text;
            Log.d(TAG, "getUserMessage: " + text + "=" + s);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void clearMmiString() throws RemoteException {
            Log.d(TAG, "clearMmiString");
        }
    };


    /**
     * Put stamp to the system log when PhoneUtils bind to the service
     * after Android has rebooted. Application must call {@link Util#syslogHasLine(String, String, String, boolean)} to 
     * check is phone rebooted or no. Without reboot phone application does not bind tom this service! 
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Do not localize!
        Log.i(TAG, LOG_STAMP);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
        filter.addDataScheme(URI_SCHEME);
        filter.addDataAuthority(URI_AUTHORITY, null);
        filter.addDataPath(URI_PATH, PatternMatcher.PATTERN_LITERAL);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        return mBinder; 
    }

    public IBinder asBinder() {
        Log.d(TAG, "asBinder");
        return mBinder;
    }

}
```

the aidl for com.android.internal.telephony

IExtendedNetworkService.aidl

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;

/**
 * Interface used to interact with extended MMI/USSD network service.
 */
interface IExtendedNetworkService {
    /**
     * Set a MMI/USSD command to ExtendedNetworkService for further process.
     * This should be called when a MMI command is placed from panel.
     * @param number the dialed MMI/USSD number.
     */
    void setMmiString(String number);

    /**
     * return the specific string which is used to prompt MMI/USSD is running
     */
    CharSequence getMmiRunningText();

    /**
     * Get specific message which should be displayed on pop-up dialog.
     * @param text original MMI/USSD message response from framework
     * @return specific user message correspond to text. null stands for no pop-up dialog need to show.
     */
    CharSequence getUserMessage(CharSequence text);

    /**
     * Clear pre-set MMI/USSD command.
     * This should be called when user cancel a pre-dialed MMI command.
     */
    void clearMmiString();
}
```

the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ussdcodes"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <receiver android:name="com.example.ussdcodes.BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".USSDDumbExtendedNetworkService" >
            <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
                <action android:name="com.android.ussd.IExtendedNetworkService" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

now the activity that uses the service (don't forgot to reboot the phone after installing the service)

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.usingussdservice;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     UssdMsg ussdMsg = new UssdMsg();
        UssdsetMmi ussdsetMmi = new UssdsetMmi();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         ussdMsg.setMainActivityHandler(this);
         ussdsetMmi.setMainActivityHandler(this);
        // com.example.ussdcodes


          IntentFilter fltr_ussdmsg = new IntentFilter("com.example.ussdcodes.getusermsg");
          registerReceiver(ussdMsg,fltr_ussdmsg);

          IntentFilter fltr_setmmistring = new IntentFilter("com.example.ussdcodes.setmmistring");
          registerReceiver(ussdsetMmi,fltr_setmmistring);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        sendUssd( ) ;
                }
    public void sendUssd( ) 
    {
        //codeToSend=*600*1*#
        String codeToSend  ;
         codeToSend = "tel:" + Uri.encode("*") + "600"+ Uri.encode("*")+"1"+ Uri.encode("#");
        // codeToSend = "tel:" + codeUssd ;
         startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
         Uri.parse(codeToSend)), 1);




    }
}
```

UssdMsg.java

```
package com.example.usingussdservice;




import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UssdMsg extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    MainActivity mainActivity = null;
    void setMainActivityHandler(MainActivity mainActivity ){
        this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
    }



    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        setMainActivityHandler(mainActivity);

         int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                 "inside UssdMsg.onReceive", duration);
    toast.show();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
      String string = bundle.getString("result");
      Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context,
              "result="+string, duration);
      toast2.show();

    }

    }   





}
```

UssdsetMmi.java

```
package com.example.usingussdservice;




import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UssdsetMmi extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    MainActivity mainActivity = null;
    void setMainActivityHandler(MainActivity mainActivity ){
        this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
    }

    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        setMainActivityHandler(mainActivity);

         int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                 "inside UssdsetMmi.onReceive", duration);
         toast.show();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
      String string = bundle.getString("ussdCode");
      Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context,
              "ussdCode="+string, duration);
      toast2.show();



    }

    }   





}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.usingussdservice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> 
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="send ussd code" />

</RelativeLayout>
```